# generate routed traffic for testing purposes

Tags: virtual-machine, routing

I have a following network setup:

```
VPS-A[WAN] <-> Internet <-> [WAN]VPS-B
```

Both `VPS-A` and `VPS-B` have `net.ipv4.ip_forward` enabled and there is a VPN tunnel between those two virtual machines. Now I would like to achieve following network topology for testing purposes:

```
VPS-X[WAN] <-> [LAN]VPS-A[WAN] <-> Internet <-> [WAN]VPS-B[LAN] <-> [WAN]VPS-Y
```

In theory I could configure `tap` interfaces both to `VPS-A` and `VPS-B`, put those `tap` interfaces into bridge, assign an IP address to this bridge and use this IP address as an default gateway for `VPS-X`(virtualized in `VPS-A`) and `VPS-Y`(virtualized in `VPS-B`). However, is there a simpler way to generate routed traffic for testing purposes?